# Will I be able to update my windows 7 PC to windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-update

My pc is from 2011, I have a Intel core 2 duo e6600 Processor, 4gb ram.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: That CPU will run the original 2015 Win10, not so sure about the latest.

Comment: The [e6600 was released in 2006](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/27250/intel-core2-duo-processor-e6600-4m-cache-2-40-ghz-1066-mhz-fsb/specifications.html). Your processor may well "run" Windows 10 but it will never be "supported". All of Microsofts officially supported processor lists are at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/windows-processor-requirements

Comment: You may have more problems with things such as graphics and other system drivers. Intel dropped support for many older systems when Windows 10 changed the way things worked. The best thing to do is to create a bootable USB, buy a new hard drive for your computer and pull out your existing one then install on the new drive. That way if it doesn't work you can simply swap the drive back and carry on.

Answer (score 1):

Some user testimonies report that upgrading this ancient CPU to Windows 10
is possible. For example:
[Can we update Windows 10 in an Intel Core 2 Duo?](https://www.quora.com/Can-we-update-Windows-10-in-an-Intel-Core-2-Duo).

The RAM you have is 4 GB, which is entirely sufficient for Windows 10.

However, you will only have limited use from this CPU, because it lacks
many modern features that current software expects to find.
For example, the SSE4 instruction set is not supported, which can cause
problems with modern games, as they require that capability.